# AWS S3 replicate with destination prefix

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Is there a way to replicate from one S3 source bucket to destination bucket with prefix in the destination bucket? I see the option to filter the prefix in the source bucket, but not the destination. Basically, trying to do what Sync/cp would do.

e.g.

```
aws s3 sync s3://<source-bucket>/prefix1/ s3://<destination-bucket>/prefix2/
```

Comment: why dont you try s3 same region replication or cross region replication?

Comment: No, Amazon S3 Same/Cross-Region Replication does not allow you to specify a different prefix for the target.

Answer (score 4):

I came across your question after researching this myself today. As John commented, no, it's not possible.

From the [ReplicationRule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_ReplicationRule.html) API documentation page, you can see that you have to specify a Destination. From the [Destination](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_Destination.html) API page, you can see that you are only able to specify a bucket ARN, and cannot specify a destination prefix.

Comment: It's annoying because the console offers the hint "Format: s3://bucket/prefix" except you'll get an error if you include the s3:// and/or add a prefix  (-_-)